# convert numbers in text file to base16 in python

Tags: python, text, hex

I have a Text File With Numbers in Base10 Format

2325552

3213245

And i want to convert the Numbers in This text File Using Python Script To Base16 Format
So the New Text file Will Be Like that Using Python Script

237C30

3107BD

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Function to convert decimal to hexadecimal

Just pass the number you want to concert to the `hex()` method and you'll get back the value in base16 (hexadecimal).

This is an example :

```py
def decimal_to_hexadecimal(dec):
    first_v = str(dec)[0]
    decimal = int(dec)
    if first_v == '-': 
        hex_dec = hex(decimal)[3:]
    else:
        hex_dec = hex(decimal)[2:]
    return hex_dec

result = decimal_to_hexadecimal(2325552)

print('result : ', result)
```

Output

> result :  237c30

Answer (score 0):

We can convert integer number to string hex and transfer string write to the file. Example we can transfer to bytearray

Comment: This answer seems correct, but could use supporting code, citations, proofreading etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use [hex()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex), a `built-in function` to convert an integer number to a lowercase hexadecimal string prefixed with “0x”

```py
>>> hex(2325552)
'0x237c30'
```

If you want to remove the `0x` prefix you the following code

```py
>>> hex(2325552)[2:]
'237c30'
```

To avoid the error in case of a `negative number` use the function described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71771055/12042898)